# What is this component? White SMD part marked "W"

Tags: identification, components

I have looked at every capacitor or resistor but I don't know what this kind is called.

Does anyone know what this component is called? It's just a letter "W" in a blue square.

[image]

This board is from a Smart TV 55" grafic board.

Comment: Only one has a W, the other has an M!

Comment: W clearly means the part is white. The one below is marmite.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It appears to be a fast acting ceramic fuse rated for 7 amperes.

It looks very much like the [Littelfuse "437 Series – 1206 Fast-Acting Fuse"](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/fuses/littelfuse_fuse_437_datasheet.pdf.pdf)

[image]

This table from the datasheet says code W is 7 amperes:

[image]

Comment: Waw. First time i see those kinds a fuses. Thanks.

Comment: Note how they skipped M. I was gonna make a joke about it being M, but they thought of that...

Comment: This thing about *soldering* fuses to the PCB still puzzles me... (Yeah, showing my age here).

Comment: You can see the FS1 and FS2 markings on the PCB, which might be related. Would point towards a fuse I believe.

Comment: I wonder how they came up with the current ratings.  They are neither R10 nor E12.

Comment: @Rmano, vexatious when they are not smd. M205's soldered to PCB's for instance.

Answer (score 13):

They are possibly [this 7 amp fuse](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/fuses/littelfuse_fuse_437_datasheet.pdf.pdf): -

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Note the silkscreen markings "FS1" and FS2", indicating they are indeed fuses.